# Retrieve file from database using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, pdf, dataframe

I have a column `FileContent` (datatype `image`) in the database which store pdf, zip and docx file.

The `FileContent` column has the following value in database: `0x2550444...`

I read the SQL table into DF using python and the values in column `FileContent` contains weird text instead of the `0x2550444...` :

> %PDF-1.7\n\n4 0 obj\n(Identity)\nendobj\n5 0 obj(Adobe)endobj8 0 obj> stream xœì½x\ÅÕ7>sïÝÞ«¶hµ»ZíJòªKV³,­Õ­b[’eK²eKVqaÝmlÜ0ÍÑƒ˜NB Á$ÙÆ¢›¼¦…’˜4JpH€ " éæÎcxóþŸïý¾G#Ÿ=¿™;3wæÌ™3gæÞ]#Œ²Ã‡€:Ê›fWÕþ°ã ’ý~+Bž£¥åó_{óÒÕ¿™€õ®ŠÒº²‹U3Â¯ý!E¤ª¼¢rÁ«|ˆ{w!..................................

Is there a way to retrieve the file or convert the text above into a file (e.g. PDF) using `python`?

Will appreciate your input. Thank you.

My ultimate goal is to:
- retrieve the file from the column `FileContent` and extract the text within the files later on.

Code:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect(server="",user="",password="",database="")
stmt = "SELECT FileContent FROM [tablename]"
df = pd.read_sql(stmt,conn)
df.head()
print(df)
```

Comment: Please let us know what database ORM you are using.

Comment: @meyer9 Hi, I'm using the module: pymssql to connect to the MSSQL database at the moment.

Comment: please post some code then. can you retrieve the text from the database?

Comment: Hi @meyer9 yes, I managed to retrieve the text shown above in yellow box in python. Have posted my code.

Answer (score 3):

Everything is fine. What you see is different representations of the same content.

0x255044... is the hexadecimal representation of the first bytes. If you look up in an ASCII table,

- 0x25 = '%'
- 0x50 = 'P'
- 0x44 = 'D'

and so on. The other text is what the .pdf looks like in a text editor. The garbled mess after "stream" is zip-compressed content within the pdf.

Just write out the whole stream into a .pdf file (use binary mode!) and try to open in Acrobat Reader.

```
with open('temp.pdf', 'wb') as outfile:
    outfile.write(pdf_content_from_database)
```

should do.

Answer (score 1):

ASCII codes for `'%PDF-1.7\n` are `'0x25'`, `'0x50'`, `'0x44'`, `'0x46'`, `'0x2d'`, `'0x31'`, `'0x2e'`, `'0x37'`, `'0xa'`

So `0x255044462d302e370a` is just the ASCII representation of that string. And `'%PDF-1.7\n` is the preamble of a pdf file. That means that you have correctly extracted the content of a PDF file from the database. You have just to save it to a file with a .pdf extension to be able to use it.

So assuming that the text above is contained in a variable `fileContent` its conversion to a pdf file is just:

```
with open('file.pdf', 'wb') as fd:   # binary mode
    fd.write(fileContent)
```

Comment: Hi @Serge Ballesta, thanks for enlightening. 
I ran the above code and got the following error: 
`fd.write(df)`
`TypeError: argument 1 must be convertible to a buffer, not DataFrame`
Code: 
`with open(r'C:\Users\XXX\Desktop\file.pdf', 'wb') as fd:   # binary mode`
`fd.write(df)`

Note: The df contains the `FileContent` column only.

Comment: @Grqm.: I'm far from expert in dataframes. You must manage to get the content of the field as a byte string. My code indeed assumes that fileContent is a Python string...